# Как определить причину PHP ошибки "Allowed memory size"?

Tags: php, mysql

На сайт загружаются файлы (песни), при том файл (содержимое) сохраняется в базу (таковы требования были, чтобы файлы в базе сохранялись). Поле, куда сохраняется содержимое, имеет тип "mediumblob". Все работает нормально.

Но при попытке загрузить файл, который весит 70мб, выдается ошибка:

> "Fatal error: llowed memory size of
>   268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 154488859 bytes) in
>   /home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
>   on line 228"

228 строка: `return $this->_stmt->execute($params);`
То есть при попытке выполнить запрос к базе.

Пытался манипулировать параметром "memory_limit". Ставил разные значения 256М, 512М, 1G, 3072М, но ситуация оставалась прежней.

По словам сисадмина, который работал с серваком и настраивал его, сервер имеет 16Гб оперативной памяти. То есть, по сути, ему должно ее хватить.

Как можно более-менее детально определить причину ошибки, чтобы знать, что и как настроить, чтобы ее исправить?

Спасибо.

Comment: > Пытался манипулировать параметром "memory_limit". Ставил разные значения 256М, 512М, 1G, 3072М, но ситуация оставалась прежней.

В рантайме, что ли?

> Но при попытке загрузить файл который весит 70мб

Копия файла в памяти + копия передаваемых данных - уже 140 мб, видимо еще две копии где-то образуются.

Comment: Ну, в плане, что я в .htaccess изменял параметр и повторно пытался загружать файл.

Comment: @walik какой сетап вообще используется? mod_php или php-fpm?

Comment: Честно точно не знаю, как можно точно узнать, что используется?  Мне кажется, что mod_php.

Comment: @walik, в общем, в ряде случаев количество выделяемой памяти можно поменять только из конфига. В вашем случае я бы попробовал не оптимизировать пока код, а попробовать подредактировать конфиге (это тупо выйдет дешевле по затратам).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй в PDO установить параметр `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY`

Comment: Попробовал так:

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SQL', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true));

Не помогло, все равно ошибка.